# Callback listener not working properly

Tags: java, android, callback, realm, listener

I'm using the [Realm library](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) for my app.
I do an asynchronous request to get object like this :

```
    public static void getMissions(final List<StatutMission> listStatus, final SListener<List<RMission>> listener) {

    final String[] statesCode = new String[listStatus.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < listStatus.size(); i++) {
        statesCode[i] = listStatus.get(i).getStateCode();
    }


    final RealmResults<RMission> results = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(RMission.class).in("state", statesCode).findAllAsync();
    results.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<RMission>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<RMission> element) {

            Log.d(TAG, element.size() + " mission(s) found in database with states " + StringUtils.arrayToString(statesCode, ","));
            listener.onResponse(Realm.getDefaultInstance().copyFromRealm(element));
            results.removeChangeListener(this);

        }
    });

}
```

The listener class :

```
public interface SListener<T> {

void onResponse(@Nullable T result);
```

}

i tested my code in multiple device but only on one device (samsung tablet) the problem.

Problem code:

```
   MissionManager.getMissions(listStatus, new SListener<List<RMission>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(List<RMission> result) {
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) `Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(...` and `Realm.getDefaultInstance().copyFromRealm(...` you are opening Realm instances that you will never be able to close, read [the docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances)

2.) you're not preserving the RealmResults as a field reference therefore the finalizer will destroy it before the asynchronous query is evaluated, therefore callback won't be called, read the docs [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications) and [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html#addChangeListener-io.realm.RealmChangeListener-)

> *From* [*javadoc*](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html#addChangeListener-io.realm.RealmChangeListener-):
>
> Registering a change listener will not prevent the underlying RealmResults from being garbage collected. ***If the RealmResults is garbage collected, the change listener will stop being triggered. To avoid this, keep a strong reference for as long as appropriate e.g. in a class variable.***
>
> ```
> public class MyActivity extends Activity {
>
>     private RealmResults<Person> results; // Strong reference to keep listeners alive
>
>     @Override
>      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>          results = realm.where(Person.class).findAllAsync();
>          results.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Person>>() {
>            @Override
>            public void onChange(RealmResults<Person> persons) {
>                // React to change
>            }
>        });
>      }
>      // remove change listeners, and close Realm in onDestroy()
>  }
> ```

3.)  all this hassle for an asynchronously evaluated query is kinda meaningless if you ***copy every single lazy-evaluated element inside the lazy-evaluated RealmResults EAGERLY, ON THE UI THREAD***, so you should reevaluate your logic, specifically after you've read [the relevant docs on how Realm queries work](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#queries).

> All fetches (including queries) are lazy in Realm, and **the data is never copied**.

As the data is never copied, there is no reason for you to use `copyFromRealm()`.

Comment: If you use RealmChangeListeners as intended, you probably wouldn't even need this `SListener`.

Comment: Thanks EpicPandaForce , the most bug was the RealmResults field reference.
I also corrected my other design problems of the lifecycle and the threads

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)